# Problem with intersection of two arrays in C

Tags: c

when trying to intersect two arrays, I'd like to show only the numbers that repeats twice , tried creating a variable that counts the number of repetitions on both arrays and put a condition, ex : if(r1 + r2>2 ) but i have trouble making it work ._.

example  :

````
#include <stdio.h>
#define N1 5
#define N2 5
#define N3 5
int main()
{
    int i=0,T1[5]={1,1,6,9,12},T2[5]={1,2,7,9,12},T3[5],j=0,k=0,tmp;


    for(i=0;i<N1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N1;j++)
        {
            if(T1[i]==T2[j]){
                T3[k]=T1[i];
                k++;}}

        }
    for(j=0;j<N1-1;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<N1-1;k++)
        {
            if(T3[k]<T3[k+1]){
                tmp=T3[k];
                T3[k]=T3[k+1];
                T3[k+1]=tmp;}
        }
    }

    for(k=0;k<N3;k++)
    {
        printf("This is the array after intersection  : T[%d] = %d\n",k,T3[k]);
    }

}```

Output : This is the array after intersection : T[0] = (random numbers)
         This is the array after intersection : T[1] = (random numbers)
         This is the array after intersection : T[2] = 12
         This is the array after intersection : T[3] = 9
         This is the array after intersection : T[4] = 1
````

Comment: Your verbal description and your code does not overlap. Sticking to your verbal proposal; first, you need to find elements that appear twice in one array, and then check whether that element exists in the other array; if exists, insert it into the the intersection array.

Comment: I didn't want to include the condition I put on the description because it was pretty messy ngl, I'll try doing that, thanks !

Comment: You can't create an intersection array just counting. Consider arrays `a = { 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 }` and `b = { 6, 7, 8 }`; when counting occurrences only, `aCount(4) + bCount(4)` will be 3, which is greater than 2 and meets your `(r1 + r2 > 2)` condition, though 4 is not in the intersection set.

Comment: @hitter Thanks for the answer ! ( also I got it for the upvoting stuff , didnt know sitll new to the site :P ), I'll look into it :P

Comment: Also i'm a freshman and I'm trying to do the intersection without involving functions since we're like on week two of arrays ( we'll be doing functions in 3-4weeks ), I do know them though so I'll try doing it with a third array ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to save the values to a third array `T3` you can simply return them, once they are found to be part of the intersection of the arrays `T1` and `T2`.
Something like the code below will work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N1 5
#define N2 5
#define N3 5

void intersection(int* T1, int* T2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    printf("The intersection of the 2 arrays is: ");
    while (i < N1 && j < N2){
        if (T1[i] < T2[j]) {
            i++;
        }
        else if (T2[j] < T1[i]) {
            j++;
        }
        else // if T1[i] == T2[j]
        {
            printf("%d ", T2[j]);
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, tmp,
        T1[N1] = { 1, 1, 6, 9, 12 },
        T2[N2] = { 1, 2, 7, 9, 12 };
    intersection(T1, T2);
    return 0;
}
```

When run this code outputs:

```
The intersection of the 2 arrays is: 1 9 12
```